# Difference between EOT and EOF

Tags: ascii

I understand that EOT is ASCII code 4, whereas EOF is encoded as -1 (at least in C).  Before I found out that EOF is mapped to -1, I thought it was just a synonym for EOT.  Why is EOF mapped to -1 rather than EOT?  As far as I can tell, they both do the same thing, which is to terminate a file stream.  The only difference I can discern is that EOT also terminates a command in the bash shell.  I would like a description of the precise technical differences between these two codes.

Comment: See [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315151/whats-the-last-character-in-a-file) question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Generally, EOF isn't a character; it's the absence of a character.

If a program runs on a terminal in canonical mode with default settings (i.e. a plain C program that just uses stdio), it will never see the ASCII character EOT. The terminal driver recognizes that character and creates an EOF condition (which at the low level is a 0 return value from `read()`). The stdio library translates that EOF condition into the return value that is appropriate for the function in question (the `EOF` macro for `getchar()`, a null pointer for `fgets()`, etc.)

The numeric value of the `EOF` macro is of no relevance anywhere but in the C library, and it shouldn't influence your understanding of the meaning of the EOF condition.

Comment: Intentionally omitted from this answer to keep it simple: the behavior of `^D` when not at the beginning of a line, and any reference to the `sizeof(int)==1` problem.

Comment: The answer needs an explanation for non-C-programmers: `read()` is a standard C library call. When the file descriptor being read is in the default blocking mode, `read()` waits until characters to read are available through the descriptor. After it reads them (into a given buffer), it returns the number of characters read. The special return value `0` indicates the end of file condition. (other special return value - indicating errors or other special conditions is `-1`)

Answer (score 5):

`EOF` in the context of C is just something that cannot appear in a file. `EOT` is an ASCII character that historically signalled the end of a message (and is a special character in UNIX terminals that means end of stream *when it appears in user input only*), but it CAN appear in files, so using it in C to signal the end of a file would be a terrible idea when reading binary files!

Answer (score 4):

EOT is one of a number of control characters used by seerial devices.  There are a number of other control characters which are related to transmission of data over serial lines or storage of files on a serial source like paper tape.  These include characters such as SOH, STX, ETX, FS, RS, GS, and, US.  Additional control characters are used for transmission control and error correction.

On a serial connection an EOT (End Of Transmission) character indicates a desire to end the transmission.  Serial connections are usually accessed using  a file driver.  When the serial transmission ends, the file driver reports this as an EOF (End Of File) condition.

EOF is not a character.  getchar() returns an integer.  A valid character while will have a value in the range 0 to 255.  The value of -1 is often used as false/invalid/fail indicator on Unix/Linux. (Actually a non 0 value, as there are any number of reasons not to succeed, but usually only one success case.)  When getchar() returns -1 it is clearly not returning a character.  However, if you store the output in a byte, you won't be able to distinguish EOF from the DEL (Delete) character.

Comment: If you use only standard 7-bit ASCII encoding, DEL is encoded as 01111111 while -1 is encoded as 11111111, so it's OK to use it as EOF.