# How to signal end-of-input to "read -N"?

Tags: bash, ksh, tty, read, user-input

I've been trying to figure out why I get a literal end-of-transmission character (EOT, ASCII code 4) in my variable if I read <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> with `read -N 1` in `bash` and `ksh93`.

I'm aware of the distinction between the end-of-transmission character and the end-of-file condition, and I know what <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> does when using `read` without `-N` (it sends EOT, and if the input was empty, the underlying `read()` returns zero, signalling EOF).

But I'm not sure why trying to read a specific number of characters changes this behaviour so radically. I would have expected an EOF condition and that the following loop would exit:

```
while read -N 1 ch; do
  printf '%s' "$ch" | od
done
```

Output when pressing <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>:

```
0000000  000004
0000001
```

The `bash` manual says about `read -N` (`ksh93` has a similar wording):

> `-N nchars`;
>                        read returns after reading exactly `nchars` characters
>                        rather than waiting for a complete line of input, **unless
>                        EOF is encountered** or read times out.

... but it says nothing about switching the TTY to raw/unbuffered mode (which is what I assume is happening).

The `-n` option to `read` seems to work in the same way with regards to <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>, and the number of characters to read doesn't seem to matter either.

How may I signal an end-of-input to `read -N` and exit the loop (other than testing the value that was read), *and why is this different from a "bare" `read`*?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/323750/70524

Comment: Very interesting issue .... By the way if you use `read -e -N 1 ch` works fine. `-e` options involves bash readline for interactive shells... Maybe this means that `read -N` works in a non interactive way while simple `read` works interactivelly.

Comment: Looking at [bash sources](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/read.def#n482), this is exactly what happens: the TTY is put in raw mode, and EOF takes effect only in canonical mode. With [`-e`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/read.def#n467) it's more complicated, but it's still not a true EOF (you can see that with `read -e -N 2 ch`).  I suppose that's a bug, i.e. the EOF should be emulated in both cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be more helpful if the doc pointed out that there's no such thing as an ASCII EOF, that the ASCII semantics for ^D is EOT, which is what the terminal driver supplies in canonical mode: it ends the current transmission, the `read`.  Programs *interpret* a 0-length read as EOF, because that's what EOF looks like on files that have that, but the terminal driver refusing to deliver character code 4 and instead swallowing it and terminating the read isn't always what you want.

That's what's going on here: control character semantics are part of canonical mode, the mode where the terminal driver buffers until it sees a character to which convention assigns a special meaning.  This is true of EOT, BS, CR and a host of others (see `stty -a` and `man termios` for alll the gory details).

`read -N` is an explicit order to just deliver the next N characters. To do that, the shell has to stop asking the terminal driver for canonical semantics.

By the way, EOF isn't actually a condition a terminal can set, or enter.

If you keep reading past eof on anything else, you'll keep getting the EOF indicator, but the only EOF the terminal driver can supply is a fake one—think about it—if the terminal driver actually delivered a real EOF, then the shell couldn't keep reading from it afterwards either.  It's all the same terminal. Here:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
char s[32];
int main(int c, char**v)
{
    do {
        c=read(0,s,sizeof s);
        printf("%d,%.*s\n",c,c,s);
    } while (c>=0);
}
```

try that on the terminal, you'll see that the terminal driver in canonical mode just interprets EOT to complete any outstanding read, and it buffers internally until it sees some canonical input terminator regardless of the read buffer size (type a line longer than 32 bytes).

The text that's confusing you¸

> unless EOF is encountered

is referring to a real EOF.

Comment: That's a long rambling that doesn't answer the OP's question: why does EOT act as EOF in `read` without `-N`, but not in `read -N`?

Comment: So, "to do that, the shell has to stop asking the terminal driver for canonical semantics" would be clearer if I didn't explain what canonical semantics are, then?

Comment: Judging from my own experience reading your post, yes, it would. Anyway, as I pointed out above, the shell could do better: look for `VEOF` in the input and emulate an EOF.  And fallback to the current behaviour if `VEOF` is not defined.

Comment: Well, as with any judgement call, there's downsides to every possible decision. I don't think there's any point insisting that EOT should have been singled out from CR and BS and the others and given extra protection. It wasn't. If you want the terminal applying canonical buffering semantics, turn them on, that gives you line buffering and all the V* semantics. If you don't want the canonical buffering semantics, turn them off, that gives you character codes straight off the keyboard.

Comment: Sure, but `bash` seems to try to hide these details from the the user (for one, the manual doesn't mention any `termios` mode changes).  Having `read -N` behave differently from `read` is unexpected if you don't know the low-level details. _shrug_

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since it, together with the comments encapsulates what it was I was looking for.