# Is there a character as `delim` of `read`, so that `read` reads the entire of a file at once?

Tags: bash, read

In bash manual, about `read` builtin command

> `-d delim` The first character of `delim` is used to terminate the input line,
>   rather than newline.

Is it possible to specify a character as `delim` of `read`, so that it never matches (unless it can match EOF, which is a character?) and `read` always reads the entire of a file at once?

Thanks.

Comment: [A file does not end with an End of File character](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/315233/65304)

Comment: Can you motivate the question with a use-case? Why does a file's contents need to end up in a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `bash` can't store NUL bytes in its variables anyway, you can always do:

```
IFS= read -rd '' var < file
```

which will store the content of the file up to the first NUL byte or the end of the file if the file has no NUL bytes (text files, by definition (by the POSIX definition at least) don't contain NUL bytes).

Another option is to store the content of the file as the array of its lines (including the line delimiter if any):

```
readarray array < file
```

You can then join them with:

```
IFS=; var="${array[*]}"
```

If the input contains NUL bytes, everything past the first occurrence on each line will be lost.

In POSIX sh syntax, you can do:

```
var=$(cat < file; echo .); var=${var%.}
```

We add a `.` which we remove afterwards to work around the fact that command substitution strips all trailing newline characters.

If the file contains NUL bytes, the behaviour will vary between implementations. `zsh` is the only shell that will preserve them (it's also the only shell that can store NUL bytes in its variables). `bash` and a few other shells just removes them, while some others choke on them and discard everything past the first NUL occurrence.

You could also store the content of the file in some encoded form like:

```
var=$(uuencode -m - < file)
```

And get it back with:

```
printf '%s\n' "$var" | uudecode
```

Or with NULs encoded as `\0000` so as to be able to use it in arguments to `printf %b` in `bash` (assuming you're not using locales where the charset is BIG5, GB18030, GBK, BIG5-HKCSC):

```
var=; while true; do
  if IFS= read -rd '' rec; then
    var+=${rec//\\/\\\\}\\0000
  else
    var+=${rec//\\/\\\\}
    break
  fi
done < file
```

And then:

```
printf %b "$var"
```

to get it back.

Comment: If the first `read` reads a file up to the first `NUL`, will the second `read` be able to read past `NUL`?

Comment: @Tim, yes, `IFS= read -rd ''` is often used in a loop to read NUL-delimited records in zsh or bash. You'll find many examples on unix.SE

Answer (score 3):

The answer is generally "no", simply because - as a general rule - there is no actual character in a file that conclusively marks the end of a file.

You are probably well advised to try a different approach, such as one of those suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984432/how-to-read-the-file-content-into-a-variable-in-one-go. Use of:

```
IFS="" contents=$(<file)
```

is particularly elegant; it causes Bash to read the contents of `file` into the variable `contents`, except for NULL-bytes, which Bash-variables can't hold (due to its internal use of C-style, NULL-byte terminated strings). `IFS=""` sets the internal field separator to empty so as to disable word splitting (and hence to avoid the removal of newlines).

Note: Since (for lack of reputation points) I can't comment on the answer suggesting the use of `read` with the `-N` option, I note here that that answer is - by definition - not guaranteed to work as it stands, because the filesize is unknown in advance.

Comment: That however removes all trailing newline characters. In `bash`, that also removes all NUL bytes.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for pointing that out; I adapted the answer to fix the issue as much as possible.

Comment: I don't get your point; should I add another 2 `0`s to `40000000` because maybe someone is going to read a 4G file into a *bash variable*, with a 128 bytes read buffer? ;-)

Comment: @pizdelect Honestly, I didn't know about the 128 bytes read buffer. Still, I'd be inclined to code something more like `fs=$(du -b file | cut -f1); read -rN${fs} contents <file`, to make the code seem a tad less arbitrary : )

Comment: @ozzy fwiw, that would better use `wc -c` instead of `du .. | cut`, and set `LC_CTYPE=C`, since the `-N` is the length in characters, not in bytes. All in all, I'm sorry that you didn't like my answer; I had tried to keep to the actual question and correct some misconceptions about the `EOF` "character", not second guess the OP (why use `read`? why read a whole file in a bash variable? why use that much `bash` in the 1st place ;-))

Comment: @pizdelect As to the byte/character difference: fair point. I think you'd need `wc -m` though, rather then `wc -c` (which according to the man page also reports bytes). As to the use of the arbitrary constant: for a one-off script, I'm sure it will do, but I'd try to avoid it; it doesn't seem clean to me.

Answer (score 2):

In `bash`, use the `-N` (number of characters) option.

```
read -rN 40000000 foo
```

Omit the `-r` option if you really want backslashes to escape characters in the file.

from `help read`:

> ```
> -N nchars return only after reading exactly NCHARS characters, unless
>    EOF is encountered or read times out, ignoring any delimiter
> ```

`EOF` is not a character, but a status: a `read` (the system call, not the shell builtin) has returned a zero length. But `getchar()` and other functions will conveniently return `EOF` which is an integer with a value (-1) that cannot conflict with any valid character from any charset. Thence the confusion, compounded by the fact that some old operating systems really did use an EOF marker (usually `^Z`) because they were only keeping track of whole blocks in the filesystem metadata.

Curiously, `read -N0` seems to does a "slow slurp" (it will read the whole file just the same, but doing a system call for each character). I'm not sure this is an intended feature ;-)

```
strace -fe trace=read ./bash -c 'echo yes | read -N0'
...
[pid  8032] read(0, "y", 1)             = 1
[pid  8032] read(0, "e", 1)             = 1
[pid  8032] read(0, "s", 1)             = 1
[pid  8032] read(0, "\n", 1)            = 1
[pid  8032] read(0, "", 1)              = 0
```

Notice that the buffer that `bash`'s `read` builtin is using is only 128 bytes, so you shouldn't read large files with it. Also, if your file is heavily utf-8, you should use `LC_CTYPE=C read ...`; otherwise `bash` will alternate reads of 128 bytes with byte-by-byte reads, making it even slower.

Comment: I'm not sure `read -N0` even makes any sense.

Comment: note that Bash can't store NUL bytes in variables, and `read` drops them so you can't get an exact copy of a file that contains them.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Oh no, it's not *that* bad ;-) It will try to read the 40000000 in 128 bytes sized chunks (strace it or look at `lbuf` in `lib/sh/zread.c`).

Comment: @ilkkachu  it's not at all obvious why truncating the file at the first NUL bytes is preferable to stripping NUL bytes. If you do the latter on an UTF-16 file, you will get something readable.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas OK for the dumb character conversion (it will read 128 bytes in one shot, then another 128 one by one). But no, bash's `read` builtin will read 128 bytes chunks even on seekable files.

Comment: I didn't say anything about preference. I just said it won't result in an exact copy of the data.